# In C++ finding sinx value with Taylor's Series

Tags: c++, trigonometry, taylor-series

I am trying to write a block of codes in C++ that calculates sinX value with Taylor's series.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// exp example
#include <cstdio>      // printf
#include <cmath>       //  exp

double toRadians(double angdeg)         //convert to radians to degree
{                                       //x is in radians
    const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
    return angdeg / 180.0 * PI;
}

double fact(double x)       //factorial function 
{                           //Simply calculates factorial for denominator
    if(x==0 || x==1)
        return 1;
    else
        x * fact(x - 1);
}

double mySin(double x)      //mySin function
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        double top = pow(-1, i) * pow(x, 2 * i + 1);  //calculation for nominator
        double bottom = fact(2 * i + 1);              //calculation for denominator
        sum = sum + top / bottom;                     //1 - x^2/2! + x^4/4! - x^6/6!
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    double param = 45, result;

    result = mySin(toRadians(param)); //This is my sin value
    cout << "Here is my homemade sin : " << result << endl;

    result = sin(param);              //This is library value
    cout << "Here is the API sin : " << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So my program works without any error. My output is exactly:

> Here is my homemade sin : nan
>   Here is the API sin:0.850904

I know I am making a big logic mistake but I couldn't find it out. It is my second week with C++. I am more familiar with Java. I coded the same thing and It worked absolutely perfect. The answers matched each other. 
Thanks for your time and attention!

Comment: Dude, don't compute the factorial and the power every time. Just think about how one term relates to the next...

Comment: Why do you use a `double` argument for the `fact()` function? Interested in calculating `3.42!` perhaps?

Comment: if you program works with any error, then what...

Comment: @pmg I think that would be the gamma function right ;)

Comment: debug, trace, unit test... learn how to test your code. that missing `return` is *sooo* obvious to catch.

Comment: Karoly Horvath-Thank you for your time and advices:)

Comment: By the way, your `mySin` does compute an approximation for `sin(x)`, by calculating `x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! ... + x^17/17!`, however your comment next to the `sum` assignment line is wrong.

Comment: ThoAppelsin, thank you for your consideration but the program worked perfect. Thank you though...

Comment: Now go and optimize this function so that it takes less CPU time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. in `fact`, you miss the return: `x*fact(x-1);` should be `return x*fact(x-1);`. You can see the compiler complaining if you turn the warnings on. For example, with GCC, calling `g++ -Wall program.cpp` gives `Warning: control reaches end of non-void function` for the factorial function.
2. The API `sin` also needs the angle in radians, so change `result=sin(param);` into `result=sin(toRadians(param));`. Generally, if in doubt about the API, consult the docs, like [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sin/).

Answer (score 0):

```
sin(x)= x- x^3/3! + x^5/5! -x^7/7! + x^9/9!
=x-x^3/2*3 (1- x^2/4*5 + x^4/4*5*6*7 + x^6/4*5*6*7*8*9)
=x - x^3/2*3 {1- x^2/4*5(1- x^2/6*7 + x^4/6*7*8*9)}
=x - x^3/2*3 [{1- x^2/4*5 ( 1- x^2/6*7 (1- x^2/8*9))}]
=x(1 - x^2/2*3 [{1- x^2/4*5 ( 1- x^2/6*7 (1- x^2/8*9))}])

double sin_series_recursion(double x, int n){
    static double r=1;

    if(n>1){

        r=1-((x*x*r)/(n*(n-1)));

        return sin_series_recursion(x,n-2);


    }else return r*x;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your codes seems to have some logical mistakes. Here is my corrected one:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double radians(double degrees)  // converts degrees to radians
{
    double radians;
    double const pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
    radians = (pi/180)*degrees;
    return radians;
}

double factorial(int x)  //calculates the factorial
{
    double fact = 1;
    for(; x >= 1 ; x--)
    {
        fact = x * fact;
    }
    return fact;
}

double power(double x,double n)  //calculates the power of x
{
    double output = 1;
    while(n>0)
    {
         output =( x*output);
         n--;
    }
    return output;
}

float sin(double radians)  //value of sine by Taylors series
{
   double a,b,c;
   float result = 0;
   for(int y=0 ; y!=9 ; y++)
   {
      a=  power(-1,y);
      b=  power(radians,(2*y)+1);
      c=  factorial((2*y)+1);
      result = result+ (a*b)/c;
   }
   return result;
}

double n,output;

int main()
{
    cout<<"enter the value\t";
    cin>>n;

    n = radians(n);
    cout<< "\nthe value in radians is\t"<< n << "\n";

    output = sin(n);

    cout<< "\nsine of the given value is\t"<< output;
    return 0;
}
```

The intention of this program was to use custom functions instead of libraries to make learning for others easy.

There are four user defined functions in this program.The first three user defined functions 'radians()', 'factorial()','power()', are apparently simple functions that perform operations as their name suggests.

The fourth function 'sin()' takes input in radians given by the function 'radians()'. The sin function uses Taylors series iterated term wise in the function's 'for(int y= 0;y!=9;y++)' loop till nine iterations to calculate the output.The 'for()' loop iterates the general mathematical expression: Term(n)=((-1)^n).(x^(2n+1))/(2n+1)!

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: In fact, this is [not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums). That’s why I asked you to add an explanation to your answer (this one, not next time), so it can help other people, not just the OP (original poster).